# How to remove specific user from item level permission through Rest API using power automate

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-rest-api, flow, power-automate, unique-permissions

I have a list with each list item has unique permission. Now I need to remove specific user from the item level permission using Power Automate.

I know there is REST endpoint for removing group but not user:

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('[LIST_TITLE]')/items([ItemID])/roleAssignments/groups/removebyid([Group_PRINCIPLE_ID])]
```

kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a REST endpoint to remove user permissions from list item.

Use this endpoint:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<listName>')/items(<ID>)/roleassignments/removeroleassignment(principalid=<userID>,roleDefId=1073741827)
```

Replace `<userID>` with the actual user ID.

**Microsoft documentation**: [Users, groups, and roles REST API reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn531432(v=office.15))

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually want to remove the user directly from the item level permission means let's saya user xyz is there having permissions showing as 'Contribute,Edit,Read'. Now if I use above api I need to make 3 http call instead I want to remove the user from the permission settings page of the item.

Comment: How and why are you adding multiple permission levels to same user on single item? is it coming from group permissions?

Answer (score 0):

To remove *all* roleassignments, use the following endpoint (with a POST):

```
<siteUrl>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<listName>')/items(<ID>)/roleassignments/removeroleassignment(principalid=<userID>)
```

Note the omission of the parameter "roleDefId".

Or, if you prefer, use a DELETE to this endpoint:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<listName>')/items(<ID>)/roleassignments
```

Note that the second approach will throw an error if the user has no existing roleassignments, whereas the first approach will not fail.